# Есть ли аналоги Google Places API Web Service?

Tags: google-maps-api, geocoding, geo-api

Хочу реализовать автокоплит в форме заполнения адреса.

1. Пользователь сначала выберает страну, и регион.
2. Потом вводит в текстовое поле город
3. Потом вводит в текстовое поле адрес

Меня полностью устраивает Place Autocomplete в Google Places API Web Service (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete).

Единственная проблема на шагах 2 и 3 нет возможности фильтровать возвращаемые города по региону и адреса по выбраному городу.

Какие еще возможны решения даной проблемы? Может кто-то сталкивался?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

На хабре есть замечательная статья: [Сравнение сервисов для автодополнения адресов в форме](http://habrahabr.ru/post/214945/), думаю она еще не потеряла своей актуальности.

PS: в своих проектах используем собственную базу КЛАДР. Т.е фактически свой сервис, заточенный под конкретные нужды